# Привязка AR к точкам на карте (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

Всем привет.

Сейчас тестирую дополненную реальность на Android. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении телефона на определённую точку, через AR показывалась 3D моделька, картинка или что-то подобное. Эту точку нужно найти по широте и долготе на карте (LatLng). С google maps разобрался. Определяю местоположение телефона, выставляю маркер, на котором должна сработать дополненная реальность, а что дальше?

Я знаю как отобразить точку исходя из азимута (сравнивая положение телефона в пространстве и реальное положение точки). Как я понял, в этом случае страдает точность обнаружения точки. Например, нельзя изменять высоту точки, которую должен находить телефон. В уроках по AR используются AR маркеры, но информации очень мало и сложно разобраться в том, как использовать их для моей задачи.

Подскажите, как, в теории, реализовать привязку координат и маркер для отображения дополненной реальности? Какой материал можно почитать для работы с AR в Android?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, жаль никто не отвечает на него, сам сталкивался с ним, единственное, что я нашёл из готового https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location, однако они вроде забили или продали этот проект, сейчас у меня не получается его запустить, но возможно если полазить внутри, можно понять концепты